# look up the elements two array in the array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I have the following to 2 arrays and array of object

```
array1 = [1,2]
array1 = [3,4]

arrayOfObj = [
{a:1, age: 20:, name: Thomas},
{a:2, age: 14:, name: Farida},
{a:3, age: 35:, name: James},
{a:4, age: 67:, name: Hellen},
]
```

I want to look up the elements in each array in the array of object to end up with the following:

```
array1=[
{a:1, age: 20:, name: Thomas},
{a:2, age: 14:, name: Farida}
]
array2=[
{a:1, age: 20:, name: Thomas},
{a:2, age: 14:, name: Farida}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object for a faster access to the objects.

By using the newly created object you can map the arrays from a number to a specific object.

```js
const array1 = [1,2]
const array2 = [3,4]
const arrayOfObj = [
  {a:1, age: 20, name: "Thomas"},
  {a:2, age: 14, name: "Farida"},
  {a:3, age: 35, name: "James"},
  {a:4, age: 67, name: "Hellen"},
];

const valueToObject = arrayOfObj.reduce((a, c) => ({...a, [c.a]: c}), {});

console.log(array1.map(n => valueToObject[n]));
console.log(array2.map(n => valueToObject[n]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```